# swift expected declaration error

Tags: swift

I hava a variable , why I can't access it there [image: there],

but if I access it in function, it's no trouble.

Comment: Try to avoid taking pictures of your code and instead copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: The question I've linked is different but the *answer* is exactly what you need to read.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: The top level of a class is for declarations like the `IBOutlet` or functions / methods / variables. All "working" code must be written in method bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your name variable to some kind of method in order for it to work such as viewDidLoad.

```
@IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    name

}
```

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't understand just `name` you need to write a full expression. It isn't that you cannot acces it